# Accessing elements of a python list separated by a special character

Tags: python, list

I have a python list which looks like this :

```
['NEW:kim:OPERATOR', 'DELETE:joe:USER_ROLE_GUEST']
```

Currently I am accessing specific portions of each element of the list like **NEW** or **joe**  by splitting each element by **:** creating a list of list like :

```
[['NEW','kim','OPERATOR'], ['DELETE','joe','USER_ROLE_GUEST']]
```

and then accessing it like `list[i][j]`.

Is there any nice pythonic way of avoiding all this and directly accessing the elements that I need ?

Comment: What are you going to do with that?>

Comment: i didn't find any relationship between `NEW` and joe..

Comment: `nice pythonic way of avoiding all this and directly accessing the elements` - it doesn't make any sense. It all depends on what you are going to do with that?

Comment: @Avinash Raj..so basically each element consists of 3 sub elements..all i want is to be able to access the sub elements in way without creating a list of lists..

Comment: you mean all in a single list?

Comment: I don't think there is a nicer way: from a Python programming point of view, the first list just contains strings whose substrings can't directly be accessed, and you're then simply better off with a list of lists or a list of dicts.

Comment: I'd go for building a list of lists. Or maybe a list of tuples, or even namedtuples. It looks to me like the first sub-field in your colon-separated list elements is a command name, with subsequent fields being data for that command. Is that correct?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr read carefully, please. OP has written what he has tried so far - splitting by `:`.

Comment: @thefourtheye..all i mean to say is that i want to avoid the overhead of creating another list..i want to access the sub elements of the elements like NEW ,kim etc as they are all separated by : . The accepted answers is what I am looking for..

Comment: also..i would appreciate it if the downvoters could give me reasons for the downvotes..as a novice programmer,who is trying to learn the nuances of the language,it is quite disheartening to see down votes on genuine programming problems..

Comment: @Amistad: Yes, there's overhead in creating a new list (if you can't create it as a list of lists in the first place). But if you need to perform accesses on most of these list elements it may be worthwhile to convert the whole thing rather than converting each string on the fly, since string splitting is _much_ slower than list indexing. And once you've built the list of lists you can drop the old list to recover its memory.

Comment: i have already had 5 down votes for a genuine problem in which i have not transgressed any of the so called rules of asking a question on SO..not cool at all..

Comment: I _suspect some downvotes came from people who didn't see code in your question and didn't read that you've already tried `.split(':')`. And some may be from people who think your question isn't suitable for SO (and should be on Code Review, with a proper code listing), since you're asking for an optimization of code that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose (which is not clear) is to **not create a new list** (which may be costly if the original list is large), and the data structure is always the same, you could split the internal string on the fly:

```
a = ['NEW:kim:OPERATOR', 'DELETE:joe:USER_ROLE_GUEST']
a[0].split(":")[0] # returns NEW
```

By the way, transforming your list in a list of tuples (or better, namedtuples) would be a better approach from a programming POV.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator expression  and pop the elements of as needed:

```
l = ['NEW:kim:OPERATOR', 'DELETE:joe:USER_ROLE_GUEST']

spl = (sub.split(":") for sub in l)
a = next(spl)
print(a[0])
b = next(spl)
print(b[0])
```

Or simply a generator expression and iterate over:

```
spl = (sub.split(":") for sub in l)

for ele in spl:
    print(ele)
['NEW', 'kim', 'OPERATOR']
['DELETE', 'joe', 'USER_ROLE_GUEST']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> def find_element(i,j,li):
...    try:
...         return li[i].split(':')[j]
...    except IndexError:
...         print 'your index is out of range'
... 
>>> l =['NEW:kim:OPERATOR', 'DELETE:joe:USER_ROLE_GUEST']
>>> find_element(1,4,l)
your index is out of range
>>> find_element(1,2,l)
'USER_ROLE_GUEST'
```

Comment: Down votes like this doesn't do any thing but annihilate the validation of Stackoverflow!

Comment: very true..my question already has 5 downvotes and I have no idea why